# Error using Email Communication Service in App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-communication-services, azure-dns

I'm using Email Communication Services on nestJs API deployed on App Service (Both from Azure) with docker-compose configuration and when I deploy to cloud the email always fails

All my app works, actually the email API also works fine at dev on my local machine, but when I do the deploy I got the same error trying to send email:

**code**: 400 BadRequest

**message**: Request body validation error. See property 'senderAddress'

**stack-trace**: RestError: Request body validation error. See property 'senderAddress'    at handleErrorResponse (/node_modules/@azure/core-client/dist/index.js:1321:19)    at deserializeResponseBody (/node_modules/@azure/core-client/dist/index.js:1256:45)    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Im using currently the provided Azure domain, but I also tried using my own domain. The problem is the same. I changes the domain associated in the Communication Services when I switched domain.

[Email domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGFsz.png)

Im using connection string to configure the email client, I debugged the senderAddress and the connectionString. Both are correctly provided on local and azure server.

```
constructor(
    @Inject(emailConfig.KEY)
    emailConf: ConfigType<typeof emailConfig>,
    firestoreService: FirestoreService,
  ) {
    const { appUrl, senderAddress, connectionString } = emailConf;
    this.senderAddress = senderAddress;
    this.emailClient = new EmailClient(connectionString);
    this.appUrl = appUrl;

    this.db = firestoreService.getDatabase();
  }
```

I also tried this solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183905/azure-communication-service-give-error-the-specifi?page=1&orderby=helpful but didn't work.

Im missing some extra configuration? Should I use some Azure auth specific service?
All resources are in the same resource group: Communication Services, Email Communication Services, DNS and App Service

Comment: Please provide the error message as a text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374096/help-center-entry-explaining-how-to-post-code-or-error-messages

Comment: Can you also post the code as text? If it is done, you can delete both the error image and the code image. Just to ease the dear StackOverflow's storage. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for information, and actually, the problem was not with the library itself, but with the way that DotEnv and docker-compose deal with the environment variables.

In both .env and docker-compose have this variable:

```
EMAIL_SENDER_ADDRESS="my-email@email.com"
```

Docker-compose do not delete the quotes. I think DotEnv library delete them, or maybe the way .env are, I don't know.

So, the result was having a senderAddress with quotes in my container and the API throws exception because it is not valid for an email.

Comment: By te way, I'm not sure If I have to keep in this way the post or maybe change the title. Because the problem was not the SDK or App Service.